# how can i delete the content outside the brackets

Tags: text-processing, sed

here is my file which contains two cloumns and separated by "\t"

```
a    HK97 family prohead protease [Lomovskayavirus C31]
b    major capsid protein [Lomovskayavirus C31]
c    gp12 [Lomovskayavirus C31]
d    gp19 [Lomovskayavirus C31]
```

and  i want wo get the file like this by sed

```
a    Lomovskayavirus C31
b    Lomovskayavirus C31
c    Lomovskayavirus C31
d    Lomovskayavirus C31
```

i have tried the command `sed 's/.*[\(.*\)].*/\1/'`, it seems useless.
so what should i change?
thanks.

Comment: Do you only expect one bracketed element in the second column? Or could there be multiple bracketed elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F '[][\t]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $3}' file
a       Lomovskayavirus C31
b       Lomovskayavirus C31
c       Lomovskayavirus C31
d       Lomovskayavirus C31
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `[` and `]`, because they have a special meaning (a collection of characters to match, we'll need that later on), so you get:

```
sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

But this will remove the first column, too, so try

```
sed 's/[ [:alnum:]]*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

so the first part will capture all alphanumeric characters and whitespaces, but not the tab, which will only remove everything after the tab.

Comment: that's awesome way, but when the file conntains " -" in "helix-turn-helix domain-containing protein [Staphylococcus phage PH15] "    i can only get the " helix-turn-helix domain-Staphylococcus phage PH15”, so what should i change!

Comment: Either add the `-` to `[ [:alnum:]-]` or use `[[:print:]]` which includes all printable characters or whitespace, but not TAB.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
perl6 -ne 'given .split(/\s+/, 2) { put (.[0], .[1].match: / <?after "[" > .+ <?before "]" > /).join("\t") };'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'given .split(/\s+/, 2) { put (.[0], .[1].comb: / "[" <(.+)> "]" /.[0]).join("\t") };'
```

Perl-family languages are a nice approach for thorny regex-problems. The two strategies above can be mixed-and-matched, which is to say you can `comb` with lookahead/lookbehind assertions, and `match` with capture markers.

Above the first example `split`s each line on `\s+` whitespace, but only into `2` two fragments. Then the first element is put, and the second element is searched for a `match` to the pattern `<?after "[" > .+ <?before "]" >`. The  `<?after … >` regex atom is Raku's positive-lookbehind assertion, and the `<?before … >` regex atom is Raku's positive-lookahead assertion. Since these assertions are zero-width, there's no need for capture markers and the match variable (`$/` or `$<>`) can be output directly.

The second example also `split`s each line on `\s+` whitespace, again only into `2` two fragments. Again the first element is put, and the second element is `comb`ed through to find `.+` one-or-more characters surrounded by `[` and `]`. Raku's `<(`…`)>` capture markers are used to exclude the brackets from the output (a `.[0]` index is added at the end to return the first `comb`ed match in the second column).

Sample Input:

```
a    HK97 family prohead protease [Lomovskayavirus C31]
b    major capsid protein [Lomovskayavirus C31]
c    gp12 [Lomovskayavirus C31]
d    gp19 [Lomovskayavirus C31]
```

Sample Output (both examples above):

```
a   Lomovskayavirus C31
b   Lomovskayavirus C31
c   Lomovskayavirus C31
d   Lomovskayavirus C31
```

Anyway, if you wanted to discard the first column, the code above simplifies to:

```perl
raku -ne 'put m/ <?after \[>  .+  <?before \]> /;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'put .comb(/ \[  <(.+)>  \] /).[0];'
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/( +)[^[]*\[([^]]*).*/\1\2/' input_file
a    Lomovskayavirus C31
b    Lomovskayavirus C31
c    Lomovskayavirus C31
d    Lomovskayavirus C31
```